# Pony.mail() Email is being sent by and to the same email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am reading [this](http://seanrucker.com/simple-ruby-on-rails-contact-form-using-activemodel-and-pony/) tutorial where it teaches to build a contact-us form. Everything worked fine, But I think the following line is not working properly.

## in inquiry.rb

```
def deliver 
    return false unless valid?
    Pony.mail({
      **:from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>),**
      :subject => "feedback",
      :body => message,
      :html_body => simple_format(message)
    })
end
```

the email is being sent by and to the same email address. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using the  gmail SMTP server. It has many disadvantages such as limited number of messages for a period. You can use smtp.mandrillapp.com instead of smtp.gmail.com.